# perl fork() exec() , child process gone wild

Tags: linux, perl, process, exec, fork

I am using `Linux` and `.sh` is in `tcsh`.

I have made a very basic [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) and [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html), but I need help in implementing safeties to it.

Basically my perl script calls a `.sh` script in a child process. But when I do `Ctrl+c` to kill the parent, the signal gets ignored by the child.

1) How do I capture the `SIGINT` for the child process as well?

2) The child process that runs the .sh script still STDOUT to the screen of the xterm. How can I remove this? I was thinking of doing running the script in the background

```
 exec("shell.sh args &");
```

But haven't tested as I need to figure out how to keep the child from going wild first.

3) The parent process(perl script) doesn't wait on the child(.sh script). So I've  read a lot about the child becoming a **zombie**??? Will it happen after the script is done? And how would I stop it?

```
$pid = fork();
if($pid < 0){
    print "Failed to fork process... Exiting";
    exit(-1);
    }
elsif ($pid ==0) {
    #child process
    exec("shell.sh args");
    exit(1);
    }
else { #execute rest of parent}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But when I do ctrl+c to kill the parent, the signal gets ignored by the child.

The signal is sent to two both the parent and the child.

```
$ perl -E'
   if (my $pid = fork()) {
      local $SIG{INT} = sub { say "Parent got SIGINT" };
      sleep;
      waitpid($pid, 0);
   } else {
      local $SIG{INT} = sub { say "Child got SIGINT" };
      sleep;
   }
'
^CParent got SIGINT
Child got SIGINT
```

If that child ignores it, it's because it started a new session or because it explicitly ignores it.

> The child procces that runs the .sh script still STDOUT to the screen of the xterm. How can I remove this?

Do the following in the child before calling `exec`:

```
open(STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null');
open(STDERR, '>', '/dev/null');
```

Actually, I would use [`open3`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Open3) to get some error checking.

```
open(local *CHILD_STDIN,  '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
open(local *CHILD_STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null') or die $!;
my $pid = open3(
   '<&CHILD_STDIN',
   '>&CHILD_STDOUT',
   '>&CHILD_STDOUT',
   'shell.sh', 'args',
);
```

> The parent process(perl script) doesn't wait on the child(.sh script). So I've read alot about the child becoming a zombie???

Children are automatically reaped when the parent exits, or if they exit after the parent exits.

```
$ perl -e'
   for (1..3) {
      exec(perl => (-e => 1)) if !fork;
   }
   sleep 1;
   system("ps");
' ; ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
26683 pts/13   00:00:00 bash
26775 pts/13   00:00:00 perl
26776 pts/13   00:00:00 perl <defunct>       <-- zombie
26777 pts/13   00:00:00 perl <defunct>       <-- zombie
26778 pts/13   00:00:00 perl <defunct>       <-- zombie
26779 pts/13   00:00:00 ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
26683 pts/13   00:00:00 bash
26780 pts/13   00:00:00 ps
                                             <-- all gone
```

If the parent exits before the children do, there's no problem.

If the parent exits shortly after the children do, there's no problem.

If the parent exits a long time after the children do, you'll want to reap them. You could do that using `wait` or `waitpid` (possibly from a `SIGCHLD` handler), or you could cause them to be automatically reaped using `$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';`. See [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html).

Comment: Improved answer to last question.

Comment: So back to the 1st question. How do I kill the child process with ctrl+C, if they both still recieve the signit? 
Do I put this in the parent $SIG{INT} = sub{ kill -9 $pid}; ?

also a related question what happens if a child has already finished before the parent executes the waitpid($pid, 0)? in the case of multiple childs forked at once(with a loop) then waited for at the end.

Comment: I can't install any modules, so should I just output the error to a file?

Comment: First, that's not true. If you can install a script, you can install a module. There's no difference. Secondly, `open3` is part of Perl. You also have the option of passing a shell command (`'shell.sh args >/dev/null 2>&1'`) although you then have to deal with properly escaping any argument you interpolate into it.

Comment: I don't have access to install modules on the linux, school issues. 
If I used  $pid = open3(
   '<&CHILD_STDIN',
   '>&CHILD_STDOUT',
   '>&CHILD_STDOUT',
   'shell.sh', 'args',
);
Does this spawn another process? Or does it replace the current one like exec. The reason I used Fork and Exec was because I didn't want the parent to wait on the child. But was afraid of creating zombie processes.

Comment: You don't need any special access. It does the same fork and exec, plus error checking. Already explained about zombies.

Answer (score 0):

Use waitpid in the parent thread: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html

```
waitpid($pid, 0);
```

You can also redirect stdout of your exec to /dev/null:

```
exec("shell.sh args > /dev/null");
```